# Chrome extension long lived connection: retrieve message from background to content

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I read [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)  and searched on other places but I can't solve this issue. I am using long-lived connections. I send a message from content script to background and after that I want to send a message from background to content script. However, I am not able to receive messages on the content file for some reason...

Content script:

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "my-channel"});

// receive messages
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
  console.log(msg); // doesn't log anything    
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('alertButton').addEventListener('click', function() { 
        // send message
        port.postMessage({myProperty: "value"});
    });
});
```

Background:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    if(port.name == "my-channel"){
        port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
           // do something
           // then send message to the content
           port.postMessage({myProperty: "value"});
        });
    }
});
```

EDIT: my manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
  "default_popup": "main_ui.html",
  "default_title": "Test Extension"
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["logic.js"]
  }],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

Comment: @wOxxOm but I am able to receive the message on the background when I click a button. Just can't send back

Comment: Hmm, then the posted code fragment is not sufficient to reveal the cause. Try debugging: set a breakpoint on port.postMessage in the background page and see if it runs at all.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

solution: I was using an old reference of "port" of when connection happened. The 2nd argument of the listener (that isn't visible there) is actually the port.